# Xamarin IOS facebook auth

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin

I am new in xamarin mobile development. And I have a question about facebook auth in Xamarin ios project.

I have webapi at backend and it has methods for external login(ExternalLogin,RegisterExternal etc). As I understood I shouldn't use my webapi and I should use component from https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios.

It works fine and as I understood it works in webview. The question is that before register that external user I need more info about user get user phone which user should type by his self.

I use Navigation controller in mainstoryboard at first view controller I have button "Facebook auth", after clicking user go to FacebookAuthViewController where I have 3 x Text Field(Surname, Name, Phone number). I want next magic when user go to this viewcontroller user will see facebook auth page and after getting access token he will see that 3 text fields(Surname, Name, Phone number), I will fill surname and name by info from his facebook account and phone number user should type by his self. When I add 3 input on view controller and didn't bind Name to text fields it works(Firstly user see webview with facebook auth after success auth he sees three input textboxes), but when I type name for any input field webview didn't appear and after clicking in main window on Facebook Auth button I only see 3 text fields. What I did wrong?
In default constructor I do next:

```
        _fb = new FacebookClient();
        nsUrl = new NSUrl(GetFacebookLoginUrl(AppId, ExtendedPermissions));

        // We delete cache and cookies so it does not remember our login information
        DeleteCacheandCookies();

        web = new UIWebView(UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame)
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,
        };

        web.LoadStarted += (webview, e) =>
        {
            NetworkActivity = true;
            //FacebookLoader.Hidden = true;
        };

        web.LoadFinished += (webview, e) =>
        {
            NetworkActivity = false;
            //FacebookLoader.Hidden = false;
            var wb = webview as UIWebView;
            FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
            if (!_fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(new Uri(wb.Request.Url.ToString()), out oauthResult))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                web.Hidden = true;
                // Facebook Granted Token
                var accessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
                //NavigationController.PushViewController(new FacebookRegisterViewController(), true);
                LoginSucceded(accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                // user cancelled login
                LoginSucceded(string.Empty);
            }
        };

        web.LoadError += (webview, args) =>
        {
            NetworkActivity = false;
            //FacebookLoader.Hidden = false;
            if (web != null)
                web.LoadHtmlString(
                    String.Format("<html><center><font size=+5 color='red'>{0}:<br>{1}</font></center></html>",
                               "An error occurred: ", args.Error.LocalizedDescription), null);
        };

        View.AddSubview(web);
        web.LoadRequest(NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(nsUrl));
```